# Tkinter get frame clicked

Tags: python, tkinter, bind, frame

In the program bellow, I would like to get which frame is clicked, among the 3.
The problem is that when I click, it is always if I was clicking on the last frame.

I use Python 3.9.2 on Windows 10, thanks for the help

```
from tkinter import *

def click_frame(event):
    print(frame.widget)

fenetre=Tk()

for i in range(0,3):
    if i==0:frame=Frame(width=500,height=50,bg="red")
    if i==1:frame=Frame(width=500,height=50,bg="green")
    if i==2:frame=Frame(width=500,height=50,bg="blue")
    frame.pack_propagate(False)
    frame.widget="frame_"+str(i)
    frame.bind("<Button-1>",click_frame)
    frame.pack()

fenetre.mainloop()
```

Comment: Bast38 please read my answer too (which does not provide an answer to your problem, but has a trick to make your code shorter), and do not forget to always accept the answer that helped you most using the grey checkmark on the left of it !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that the `frame` you use in `click_frame` is not an argument of your function so it is the `frame` after your for loop, i.e. the last frame "frame_2".

Instead of `frame`, you should use `event.widget` which corresponds to the actual widget that triggered the event:

```
def click_frame(event):
    print(event.widget.widget)
```

Comment: Why does your example use `event.widget.widget` instead of `event.widget`?

Comment: @BryanOakley the second `.widget` is an attribute defined by the OP in the code sample from the question, I just replaced the `frame` in the function by `event.widget`.

Comment: @j_4321: ah, I see. Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 0):

Additionally to the answer of @j_4321, you can use an array with the color names instead of the if statements. So your complete code would look like this:

```py
from tkinter import *

def click_frame(event):
    print(event.widget.widget)

fenetre = Tk()

for color in ["red", "green", "blue"]:
    frame = Frame(width=500, height=50, bg=col)
    
    frame.pack_propagate(False)
    frame.widget = "frame_" + i
    frame.bind("<Button-1>", click_frame)
    frame.pack()

fenetre.mainloop()
```

Comment: Hello,  could you tell me how to print frame names if different names? All frames here are just "frame = Frame", but if my frames are  apple_frame= Frame...etc, linux_frame= Frame...etc, micros_frame = Frame...etc . Thanks in advance.

Comment: @pkanda do you mean how to automatically name the variables `apple_frame`, `linux_frame`, etc. when you have a list `["apple", "linux", …]` ? Or do you mean how to get `"apple"`, `"linux", etc.` back from the `Frame` objects later ?

Answer (score 0):

thank you for your answer. But after posting I fond out a shortcut to solve the problem:
I removed the "for in loop" and I used the code individually for each frame, ex:

```
apple_frame = Frame(width=500, height=50, bg=col)
apple_frame.widget = "apple_frame" 
apple_frame.bind("<Button-1>", click_frame)
```

Each time I click in a new frame, frame name is printed. Have a great day!